# Retrieving received SMS with iOS 10 Messages API

Tags: sms, ios10, imessage

Is there a way I can retrieve received messages and save them in a host app using an iMessage extension ?

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely no way. This is a question of privacy, Apple will never let any extension read/save messages from users.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/224/ :

```
Apple is very, very concerned about user privacy and we really very highly value the privacy of our customers, so we don't expose contact information at all to iMessage apps.
```

The only thing you can do, is retrieving messages sent via your iMessage extension, within certain conditions (if the user has selected the message for instance)